# Define XULRUNNER default window url

Tags: url, window.open, xulrunner

I need to do a simple task but it looks like very heavy for me, i need to create XULRUNNER system which opens WWW.test.com in default window without address bar or any menu and nothing more, here are my codes but it doesn't seem to be working, can anybody help?

main.js

```js
function url() {
  windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.test.com/", "test_WindowName", strWindowFeatures);
}
```

main.xul

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="main" title="My App" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://myapp/content/main.js"/>
</window>
```

pref.js

```js
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://myapp/content/main.xul");
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeFeatures", "chrome,dialog=no,all");
 pref("toolkit.singletonWindowType", "xulmine");

/* debugging prefs, disable these before you deploy your application! */
pref("browser.dom.window.dump.enabled", true);
pref("javascript.options.showInConsole", true);
pref("javascript.options.strict", true);
pref("nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache", true);
pref("nglayout.debug.disable_xul_fastload", true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `<browser>` element

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="main" title="My App" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/javascript" src="chrome://myapp/content/main.js"/>

    <vbox id="browerbox" flex="1">
        <browser flex="1" id="testbrowser" src="http://www.test.com/ />
    </vbox>

</window>
```

The browser is very powerful element I would read up on all `Attributes`, `Properties` and `Methods` that you can use with it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/browser. What I gave you above will work but depending on what you ultimately need to do, you may need make a few changes.

Comment: thanks it works like a charm , but i have another problem, when i click a link which should open in new window, XULRunner disappears while it is still running and i can see it in task manager.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't got that far in learning how to handle links. While digging around I have seen some info out there but haven't needed to use it yet.